# Зависает android приложение собранное для устройства на Embarcadero® Delphi 10.3

Tags: android, delphi, delphi-10.3-rio, delphi-xe8

Приложение (просто 1 форма и 1 кнопка (закрывает форму)) собранное в Embarcadero Delphi 10.3 Version 26.0.34749.6593 зависает после запуска. 
Лог Rad Studio [ссылка на лог](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1L2ZhqGTOz3OMZDfPfFIawSmXbueXpgSH).Информация об устройстве:
[image: info device]

Тестовый проект (Project1) [ссылка](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1Wji-I2-E0fnVMmUCDQpfQBM7nxFzSnsH)

logcat (Project1) google drive [logcat](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1dhwx2Lj063yLYuOO2LG9OZfHuTCi7Gq2)
logcat (Project1) mega [logcat](https://mega.nz/#!j6JURa6D!GhfA8vszarM1K9i0VC0Oj-3HmLa-C6OVoNj4_rB33_E)

Аналогичное приложение собранное в Embarcadero® RAD Studio XE8 Version 22.0.19908.869 работает на данном устройстве без проблем.
Настройки SDK, NDK, JDK, TOOLS идентичное в обоих случаях:

[image: NDK][image: SDK]

, apk на телефоне redmi 5a запускается и работает без проблем. Что возможно предпринять для работы приложения? (изменить настройки SDK, NDK, подключить библиотеки для совместимости?)

Comment: Подключите logCat и посмотрите что ваше приложение в него выдает

Comment: Вопросы с просьбами помочь с отладкой («почему этот код не работает?») должны включать желаемое поведение, конкретную проблему или ошибку и минимальный код для её воспроизведения прямо в вопросе. Вопросы без явного описания проблемы бесполезны для остальных посетителей. Пожалуйста разместите минимальный лог в вопросе (кнопка "править").

Comment: Не могу пройти по ссылке, точно нельзя текст в вопрос включить?